# Reading files from Android devices using WebUSB on Windows

Tags: mtp, webusb

I was wondering whether it is possible implement a subset of MTP on top of WebUSB, connect to an Android device from Windows, and retrieve files from the device?

If I install a WinUSB driver with Zadig, I can claim the interface. However, when I try to use the default "MTP USB Device" driver, I'm not able to claim the interface. I'm assuming that this is because the Windows MTP stack automatically claims the interface, even if the "MTP USB Device" is also a WinUSB driver?

The reason why I can't just use the WinUSB driver from Zadig, is that it breaks MTP access for programs that use the Windows Portable Device API. Is it at all possible to create a USB driver that will allow both MTP access and USB access, to allow for a user-space MTP driver, as there's no MTP functionality built into Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to share access to the device between two low-level USB drivers (MTP and Chrome) is likely to cause data corruption if the device cannot differentiate between requests from each. I am not too familiar with the MTP driver built into Windows but this is a place where the experimental [Native File System API](https://wicg.github.io/native-file-system/) should be able to provide access to the device at a high level where access can be shared.

Comment: I agree, the Native File System API does sound like the way to go, but it doesn't appear to support Android devices at the moment, so I've filed a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1094835

It would also require some changes to the file picker UI, so I've voiced my support for the suggestion here: https://github.com/WICG/native-file-system/issues/180